# How to add all pages to cache.addAll

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) that I can cache files.

How can I add all pages in cache?

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v2').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/News/NewsItem/1',
        '/News/NewsItem/8',
        '/News/NewsItem/12',
        '/News/NewsItem/14',
        ...
      ]);
    })
  );
});
```

Service worker hasn't access to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the service worker does not need access to the DOM.

Here is the function I use for the service worker installation process:

```
var config = {
    cacheName: 'v01',
    staticCacheItems: [
        'News/NewsItem/1',
        'News/NewsItem/8',
        'News/NewsItem/12',
        'News/NewsItem/14'
    ],
};

self.addEventListener('install', onInstall);

function onInstall(event) {
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(config.cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(config.staticCacheItems).then(function() {
            return self.skipWaiting();
        });
    }));
}
```

Comment: OK. But how can I tranfer to service worker pages ('/News/NewsItem/1', '/News/NewsItem/8',..) to cache them? Main page has references to the news and I need cache news.

Comment: Edited to use your news links. If you need to get the links from the DOM, maybe you should try something like [prefetching](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/).

Comment: No, I don't know links in advance. User opens web site and I use jquery to create array with all links on main page. How can I tranfer this array to staticCacheItems?

Comment: Also, Admin can add new news (e.g. News/NewsItem/15) and I should cache it too. So, I can parse main page and create array of links, but I don't know how I can tranfer it to service worker (user should be able to open all news in offline mode).

Comment: Service Workers don't have access to the DOM. If you want to cache the elements, you have 2 options: **cache them after visited** or **prefetch them before using an other system**. For this second one, you could just [prefetch the elements](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/) or use a javascript library like [InstantClick](http://instantclick.io/)